# try to fix SonarQube bug - A "NullPointerException" could be thrown

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

I am facing one strange Sonar issue - A "NullPointerException" could be thrown.

Below is my service implementation class. emailNotificationServiceClient is FeignClient Interface which works fine.

```
      try {
        // send POST request
        ResponseEntity<GenericRes<?>> response = emailNotificationServiceClient.sendEmail(payload);
        // check response
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK)
                log.info("Email Send Successful : {}", response.getBody());
            else
                log.info("Email Send Failed : {}", response.getBody());

            if (response.getBody() != null && response.getBody().getMessage() != null && !response.getBody().getMessage().isEmpty())
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response.getBody().getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while sending email - sendEmailNotification in esb", e);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(e.getMessage());
    }
```

GenericRes class -

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GenericRes<T> {

    private String message;
    
    private T data;

}
```

I know that I have to add null check for object and then I should use that object. I have tried that but it won't work.

[image]

I have also tried Java 8 Optional.ofNullable but still facing same problem.

[image]

Comment: As a side note, you should probably be checking `getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()`, since sending mail is _particularly_ likely to send you back a 202.

Comment: Try do `String body = response.getBody(); if (body != null) {/*do whatever you want with body*/}`

Comment: @Ofek response is object ResponseEntity class. And ResponseEntity.getBody is object type and String type.

Comment: Instead of `String` put `GenericRes<?>`

Comment: Thank you @Ofek. It working fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a false positive.  SonarCube's rule is a bit "dumb".  But you should be able to help it out ... something like this:

```
GenericRes<?> body = response.getBody();
if (body != null) {
    String message = body.getMessage();
    if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(message);
    }
}
```

To my mind, that is *more readable* than the versions that SonarCube is having trouble with.  So, that is a "win - win" solution.

Answer (score 0):

its reported here. There is bug in the sonar.
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/java-s2259-a-nullpointerexception-could-be-thrown-getmessage-can-return-null/78815